# Android:How to make two views align-center?

Tags: android, xml

I want to achieve this:
[image]

What should I do to make the blue "+" align-center with the bottom line of the orange area? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you post some code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Post your code as well.

Comment: I just have a orange Linearlayout and a TextView below it. I have no idea what to do with the blue plus. @Amulya Khare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is using code. Set top padding of "+" view, it should be :

**topPadding=orangeHeight - plusViewHeight/2**

Of course you should do that after views appearance so the can return you non zero height value.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the height you want. Make sure you set the imageview

Attribute:

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

xml :

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:background="#d34520"
            android:textColor="#fffff"
            android:text="HTML 5 everywher....." />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="The web platform....." />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
            android:src="@drawable/plus" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Fixing height of layouts never good on all devices. Better to slice images for different screen sizes use `wrap_content` or `match_parent` to show up for different devices at the same time.

Comment: Yes I agree on your fixing height is not good. however having different layout files for respective dimensions may be a good option.Adding images may increase the size of the app.

Comment: The text of the two TextView is not permanent, it may be very long or very short. So i think this way is not very good.

Comment: In that case you can set the layout as wrap content. whatever the content is you have textviews. Keep those textviews inside relative layout and add image view with the attribute android:layout_centerVertical="true" and keep left margin of your choice..

Comment: But if i set the two textview's layout as wrap content, then their height may not be equal. The imageview has been set android:layout_centerVertical="true"  ,so the imageview will just be at the center of the relativelayout, not the dividing line of the two TextViews which i expect. @Dhina

Comment: IMHO, I feel you will have to set height for textviews wrt different layout(mdpi,hdpi etc,) as you need both the textviews of to be same height. so irrespective of text content they will be of equal size in result your plus sign will be in center. Sorry for my previous comment it was a stupid view to have wrap content :P

Answer (score 0):

This is all about your designing techniques if you want to achieve your target. Follow the steps below:

**Step 1:**

design four images named it as  1) `btn_back.png` 2) `lay1.png` 3) `lay2.png` and 4) `btn_plus.png` it will looks like this:

**1) btn_back**

[image]

**2) lay1.png**

[image]

**3) lay2.png**

[image]

**4) btn_plus.png**

[image]

**Step 2:**

Now paste the below code in your xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/lay1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="30dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Type your text here what ever you want..." />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_back"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPlus"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_plus" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/lay2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="30dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Type your text here what ever you want..." />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And you are done you will get the desired result :)

Comment: This way works, but it's not very good. Because the bottom of the plus may be below the top of the lay2 in your xml.

Comment: @hanswim bottom of the plus is white color you cannot see it here because answer editor background is also white. Try it I have got the result by testing it